# Flow can not decide which case to select and shows unrelated code

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a flow error (see it below) that makes no sense to me. First, this code was passing before, I didn't changed anything apart from removing all non necessary JSX braces `<div id={'x'}/> => <div id="x"/>`
All the components shown here accept a react `Node` as children, so anything that can be a react node can be used. I don't understand what flow is trying to say me. `__` is a function that returns string, and all the other things are just JSX tags.

The NewInputLabel code does not includes references to any of the provided "cases"

```
import type { translator } from 'components/polyglotProvider'
import polyglotProvider from 'components/polyglotProvider'
import React, { type Node } from 'react'
import phrases from './InputLabel.phrases'

type Props = {
  __: translator,
  children: Node,
  className?: string,
  htmlFor?: string,
  hint?: Node,
  optionalField: boolean,
  withoutSpacing: boolean,
}

const NewInputLabel = ({
  __,
  children,
  className,
  htmlFor,
  hint,
  optionalField,
  withoutSpacing,
}: Props) => {
  if (!children) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <label
      htmlFor={htmlFor}
      className={className}
    >
      <Overline1>{children}</Overline1>
      {optionalField && <Body2 color="light"> {__('addOns.optional')}</Body2>}
      {hint && <IconHint caption={hint} />}
    </label>
  )
}

NewInputLabel.defaultProps = {
  optionalField: false,
  withoutSpacing: false,
}

export default polyglotProvider(phrases)(NewInputLabel)
```

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/components/Form/Address/AddressFieldset.js:107:9

Could not decide which case to select, since case 1 [1] may work but if it doesn't case 2 [2] looks promising too. To
fix add a type annotation to label [3].

     src/components/Form/Address/AddressFieldset.js
     104│
     105│     return (
     106│       <div className={this._className()}>
 [3] 107│         <NewInputLabel htmlFor={this._street()}>{label}</NewInputLabel>
     108│         <Input
     109│           form={form}
     110│           name={this._street()}

     src/components/Form/DateRangeInput/DateRangeInput.js
 [1]  46│         {label ? <NewInputLabel>{label}</NewInputLabel> : null}

     src/components/Form/DateTimeRangeInput/DateTimeRangeInput.js
 [2] 133│         <NewInputLabel>{label}</NewInputLabel>
      <NewInputLabel>{label}</NewInputLabel>
```

The snippet may not be the best to read, so here is an screenshot with proper coloring:
[image: better view]

Answer (score 1):

The below error is basically saying that flow is trying to statically analyse your code and give you type inference but it can't because `case 2` and `case 3` both could be used. What it's asking you to do is provide some indicator such as type annotation that may only apply to one of the cases so that it can be sure of which component should be referenced for typing.

> Could not decide which case to select, since case 2 [1] may work but if it doesn't case 3 [2] looks promising too. To fix add a type annotation to FlexContainer element

Now the reason this is happening anyone's guess I think, because I can't see your whole project to understand how these files are connected.

But potentially could be that deep inside `NewInputLabel` there are conditions that are too loose and need to be refined more, because `React.Node` itself is a union of a number of things.

Comment: That is not the case, the code of NewInputLabel is very simple. I just updated to add the code of the NewInputLabel. As you can see, there are no references to the two mentioned cases. They are all on 3 separate files and they don't have anything to do between them. This is extremely confusing.

Comment: How are the files, AddressFieldset, DateRangeInput and DateTimeRangeInput connected? Without knowing this and seeing the whole project, it's hard to decipher